# Is it possible to change Allure timeline, so that it will show a different timeline for each Selenium Node?

Tags: allure

I am running some Selenium Tests on Jenkins with several Selenium Nodes managed by a Selenium Grid. For reporting I use the Allure Plugin. It is hard to see afterwards on which selenium node the test has run (currently i do this with Step info, but that way I first have to click on a tests details to see it).

So I was thinking it might be a good idea to alter the timeline in Allure Report, so that instead of all tests being listed under the executing Jenkins master, there could be different timelines for each Selenium Node. I did not find a way to do this, or where the timeline is generated, so I am just asking if this is even possible and where could I realize it if it is? Or do you have any other idea how to make it more clear on which node the test-browser was executed?

Comment: I believe the timeline lists tests that ran per thread. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible to change the title of the Timeline page. It is also possible to have multiple titles.

For each test case a file is created. In the Test Case description section there are labels. Labels can be made with several names, but for the time line there are two that influence what you're looking for:

- thread
- host

For each found host a title bar is generated and for each found unique thread a thread row is generated. For every found test case with that thread a block is added for the duration of the test case.

The Test Case section looks like this in the XML file:

```
<test-case severity="None" start="1483868031834" status="passed" stop="1483868031840">
  <description>Test 1</description>
  <name>Test 1</name>
  <labels>
    <label name="thread" value="28216"/>
    <label name="host" value="Apple"/>
    </labels>
  <attachments/>
  ...
```

The rest of the file contains the steps, which I believe you're already familiar with.

## -- Edit --

You can implement this by calling

```
  Allure.LIFECYCLE.fire(new CustomTestCaseEvent(host));
```

The CustomTestCaseEvent can look like the following (there probably is a more elegant way to do this):

```
public class CustomTestCaseEvent implements TestCaseEvent {
final private String host;
public CustomTestCaseEvent(final String host) {
    this.host = host;
}
@Override
public void process(final TestCaseResult context) {
    for (final Label label : context.getLabels()) {
        if ("host".equals(label.getName())) {
            label.setValue(host);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Motivated by your answer I had a look at the code again and managed to alter the timeline like I wanted!! All you have to do is fire a ´TestCaseEvent´ to the ´Allure.LIFECYCLE´, which will update the label value for the host.